# Polar curve equation with plus-minus sign (±) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, trigonometry, curve, polar-coordinates

I am trying to draw polar curves on HTML canvas using Javascript. What should I do when I want to convert plus-minus sign `(±)`?

Example: Watt's curve

[image: Math representation of Watt's curve]

Below is what I tried. Since I need to get value of `r`, I enclose entire equation with square root, also I use it's absolute value, otherwise I get `null` for trying to get square root if number is negative. Following code draws something that looks like a polar curve, but not Watt's curve.

```
var a = 1;
var b = 1;
var c = 2;
r = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(Math.pow(b, 2) - Math.pow(a * Math.sin(t) * Math.sqrt(Math.abs(Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(a, 2) * Math.pow(Math.cos(t), 2), 2)), 2) ));
```

I get similar deviations of expected results with other equations containing plus-minus sign (ones without it work fine), so I suppose the problem is that I wrongly 'translate' this symbol. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is an incorrect multiplication of a squared theta with the inner square root (`Math.sin(t) * Math.sqrt(...)`).

To plot the equation, convert the plus-minus sign into two equations:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 1;
var c = 2;

var b2 = Math.pow(b, 2);
var asint = a * Math.sin(t);
var sqroot = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(a, 2) * Math.pow(Math.cos(t), 2), 2);

var r = Math.sqrt(b2 - Math.pow(asint + sqroot, 2));
// now plot r
r = Math.sqrt(b2 - Math.pow(asint - sqroot, 2));
// now plot r again
```

The `Math.abs()` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. Somehow I thought it shouldn't be necessary. Thanks a lot.